# How to un-stick a schrader valve on high side of AC

Tags: ford, ac, leak, mustang

I have a 2007 Ford V6 Mustang that has a stuck high-side A/C Schrader valve.

The system is evacuated and without pressure but the schrader valve will not turn. I've ruined two tools because the little arms just twist off. Even putting the tips of needle nosed pliers down there and turning just doesn't budge it.

Is that normal? I'm pretty sure this valve is leaking because the leak detector beeps when it's near it and there is leak detector dye down in the well where this valve is. So I don't think penetrating oil is going to help anything.

Do I have to replace the hose assembly that contains the valve to do it?

Comment: Are you turning the valve clockwise? Some of them are left hand thread and not right hand thread like on tire valve stems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you need a better Schrader valve core removal tool. It's going to cost a few more denaro, but will take out the core without shearing off the little nibs. If they are built right, the metal will withstand the torque and the outside of the valve (the brass part you thread the core into) will help support it. This really should be a non-issue with a good tool. Spend the money and *Get 'er Done!*

Answer (score 1):

duh---its not that simple.  134A is very corrosive and the schrader valve is STUCK.  Obviously if it were not- he could and would have been able to get it off.  I would put a few drops of the correct oil on top of the valve core- and heat up the area from the outside- where the schrader valve is.  Then keep making an effort to remove it----Dont do it so hard that you sheer off the tool- just keep the heat and oil on it- and you can tap the tool with a hammer---gently--the goal of the heat is to allow the oil to get down in the threads and to break up any corrosion.  YOU must keep the area wet with the refrigerant oil- pag whatever (your car calls for).

It might take some time---so don't try to rush.